# Congruent Transformation and Wedge Product

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $V$ be a three-dimensional Euclidean space.
Let $T$ be a congruent transformation over $V$.
Let $v$ and $w$ be two vectors in $V$.
Is there an interesting relation between $(Tv)\wedge (Tw)$ and $T(v\wedge w)$?

This is an exercise from an introductory book on differential geometry.

Comment: Does $v\wedge w$ mean a bivector (signed area) or vector to you?

Answer (score 1):

If $v\wedge w$ is vector to you, then $T(v\wedge w) = \pm T(v)\wedge T(w)$, where you can decide which sign you get by finding the determinant of $T$.

For reference, the general way to calculate $T(v)\wedge T(w)$ is by finding the matrix $M$ which represents $T$, then the formula for any linear transformation $T$ is given by $$(Mv)\wedge (Mw)=\det(M)M^{-T}(v\wedge w)$$

---

If $v\wedge w$ is a bivector to you, then technically the same transformation $T$ can't act on both vectors and bivectors.  If you see $T(v\wedge w)$, what this actually means is the outermorphism of the linear transformation $T$.  When that's clear, often the same notation is used for both the linear transformation and its outermorphism.  When it's not, we use some other notation: I prefer $\underline T$.  The outermorphism $\underline T$ is defined as the unique linear transformation satisfying:

$$ \underline{\mathsf{T}}(x) = T(x)\\ 
 \underline{\mathsf{T}}(A \wedge B) = \underline{\mathsf{T}}(A) \wedge \underline{\mathsf{T}}(B)\\
 \underline{\mathsf{T}}(A + B) = \underline{\mathsf{T}}(A) + \underline{\mathsf{T}}(B)\\
 \underline{\mathsf{T}}(1) = 1 $$

for any multivectors $A$ and $B$ and any vector $x$.  Thus, by definition $\underline T(v\wedge w) = T(v)\wedge T(w)$ for *any* type of linear transformation -- including congruent transformations.

Comment: $v\wedge w$ is a bivector for me. If I set $e_1\wedge e_2 = e_3$ (and the other two equations), can I derive it directly, without referring to outermorphism?

Comment: If $e_1 \wedge e_2 = e_3$ to you, then $v\wedge w$ is just a vector for you.  Look at the top section instead.  And so that people don't misunderstand in the future, I'd suggest you use the more standard $\times$ notation instead of $\wedge$.